# Issue while importing the data from mysql to hbase

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I am getting the following error message while importing the data from my mysql to HBase using sqoop. Here is my command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoop --username root --password welcome --table employee --hbase-table employeeHBase --columns empid,empname,salray --column-family hbase_table_col --hbase-row-key empid --hbase-create-table
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:222)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:264)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Could you please help me out on this.

FYI, I have made all the necessary installation and environment is sourced.

Comment: what is the HBase version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the compatible version and its working fine.. thanks Anil

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception usually means that you are using an Incompatible version of Client. Please make sure that HBase client and server jar version is same.

Comment: Apologies for the delay as I was out of station.  could you please suggest compatible version such that sqoop would work fine and I will be able to migrate the data from mysql to hbase

Comment: Versions are: Hadoop Version; 2.6.0      Hbase: 1.0.1    SQOOP: 1.46